# Accessibility concerns for website providing massive amounts of PDFs

Tags: pdf, accessibility

I am working on a website providing massive amount of PDFs for download and I am trying to improve the website accessibility. All I can think of is:

1. Provide equivalent content for the PDFs when possible (text or HTML for example).
2. Provide description for the PDF documents before the use can download them.
3. Make it possible to search within the PDF files when the users use the website search.
4. Make the links to the PDFs labelled by a nice icon.
5. Inform the users that they will need a third party application (Acrobat or other PDF viewers) in order to open the documents.

Are there other ways to improve it?

Comment: I would ask http://libraries.stackexchange.com/

Comment: While having the PDF available in HTML is nice it isn't that important. I'm a screen reader user and Adobe Reader's assistive technology support is pretty good for PDF's that are primarily text.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Jared , it's great to hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jared said, assistive technology works decently with PDFs. The question is what kind of quality control do you have. There is a few different ways of putting together a PDF. One way is scanning a document and the result is a PDF made out of images. When assistive technology hits it, all it says is image image image, great help right?

Now Adobe built in an Optical Character Recognition ability (second way), which has improved over the years, but is far from quality. For example, I was given a PDF that had OCR on it. One of the first lines had the word Articles, in italics, the OCR spit out `Art/e5`. The third way is to produce PDFs containing actual text. Now Office 2007/2010, have the ability to save as a PDF. Before hitting save, click the options button and ensure the "document tags for accessibility" box is checked.

PDFs have a tag structure, like HTML, found via the Tags panel/pane. The output in 2010, is a bit cleaner than 2007, but I still recommend something like Commonlook Office to create your PDFs.

> 4.Make the links to the PDFs labelled by a nice icon.

You could put an icon within the link. Some people do:

```
<a href="...">Link text</a> <img src=".." alt="PDF icon"/>
```

Some people using assistive tech just browse via links, so they won't know it is a PDF before they open it. So, it is better to do:

```
<a href="....">Link text <img src="" alt="PDF"/></a>
```

> 5.Inform the users that they will need a third party application (Acrobat or other PDF viewers) in order to open the documents.

It is a good idea to do this, in fact Section 508 requirements say to  do this. I recommend linking to Adobe Reader for two reasons.

1- if the person does not have a PDF viewer, they'll probably call their "computer expert" who probably heard of Adobe Reader, and knows the site isn't pushing some ad-ware.
  2- Adobe Reader has the most built-in accessibility of the readers out there, to my knowledge. So, why would you not give the best.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to improve the accessibility of the PDFs themselves.

- Provide "Alternate Descriptions" for images
- Provide "Replacement Text" for items such as equations or abbreviations
- Replacement Text can also be used to hint at the pronunciation of names
- Mark the language, especially if it is mixed

This will assist a screen reader in properly understanding the PDF.  This isn't crucial for pages that contain only text in regular paragraph layout - the reader can usually figure things out.  If there are pictures, captions, jargon, names, etc, this will greatly improve the reader's performance.